# Find a time if it already exists in databse

Tags: php, mysql

I have had mysql query to check any particular reservations existing in database . These conditions are working in patient doctor reservation system

**Background**  :
I have system which checks available time slots .And displays next available time . As per system my next available time is 9:15 AM to 10:45 AM . But there in admin side I've set a reservation 10:00AM to 10:30,this is set by admin . So I need to show users a message "There is   a booking between the requested time 9:15 to 10:45 .You can't use the entire time" .

I wrote a query but its not working ,its not giving any results

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservation
WHERE facility_id =  '24'
AND (
'2012-03-02 09:15:00' >= CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_time,  ':00' ) 
AND  '2012-03-02 09:15:00' <= CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_end_time,  ':00' )
)
AND  '2012-03-02 10:45:00' >= ( CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_time,  ':00' ) 
AND  '2012-03-02 10:45:00' <= CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_end_time,  ':00' ) )
```

Anyone can tell  me any problem with my query .

Comment: date should be handled as dates: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: See [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't work becouse you are comparing strings not datetime values. use for example [`Date_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservation
WHERE facility_id =  '24'
AND (
 DATE_FORMAT('2012-03-02 09:15:00' , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") 
 >= 
 DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_time,  ':00' ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") 
AND  
...
```

**BTW:** This is a bad design, it would be be easier if `reservation_date` is  a `datetime`, then you can directly compare the two values using `BETWEEN` or without all these casting.

Answer (score 0):

try to cast the fields to datetime fields.. like this:

```
CAST('2012-03-02 09:15:00' AS DATETIME)
```

in your sample your where will be look like this:

```
AND (
CAST('2012-03-02 09:15:00' AS DATETIME) >= CAST(CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_time,  ':00' ) AS DATETIME)
AND  CAST('2012-03-02 09:15:00' AS DATETIME) <= CAST(CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_end_time,  ':00' ) AS DATETIME)
)
AND  CAST('2012-03-02 10:45:00' AS DATETIME) >= ( CAST(CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_time,  ':00' )  AS DATETIME)
AND  CAST('2012-03-02 10:45:00' AS DATETIME) <= CAST(CONCAT( reservation_date,  ' ', reservation_end_time,  ':00' ) AS DATETIME) )
```